# Xamarin.forms make phone call without going to dialer in Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin.forms app, I can call a specified phone number using Xamarin.Essential plugin. The problem I am facing is, when I click to call on my app in Android it will open the phone dialer and the user should manually click call.

In iOS, it will directly place a call without going to the dialer. What my intention is to prevent editing of the number in the dialer.

So, How can I call the number without going into dialer instead it should show calling screen directly in android? I have seen many posts, but I didn't get any ideas. Any help is appreciated.

I am making a call using xamarin.Essential plugin like this

```
PhoneDialer.Open(PhoneNumber.Text);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To place a phone call directly, you can use **[Xam.Plugins.Messaging](https://github.com/cjlotz/Xamarin.Plugins/blob/master/Messaging/README.md)** library:

After installing the nuget, [add this line](https://github.com/cjlotz/Xamarin.Plugins/blob/master/Messaging/Details.md#autodial-android) in Android project MainActivity's OnCreate method:

```
CrossMessaging.Current.Settings().Phone.AutoDial = true;
```

Now you can place any call directly like below:

```
var phoneDialer = CrossMessaging.Current.PhoneDialer;
if (phoneDialer.CanMakePhoneCall)
   phoneDialer.MakePhoneCall("+27219333000");
```

> Please note using this settings requires the
>   android.permission.CALL_PHONE added to the manifest file.

Comment: Let me check bro

Comment: Hi , should I add run time permission for calling? Bcz it throws an exception like "Java.Lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent
{ act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:x-xxx-xxxxxxx cmp=com.android.server.telecom/.components.UserCallActivity } "

Comment: Yes you're right, it was mentioned in the library doc link I mentioned though. Let me update the answer.