# Xamarin.Forms - Missing Intent Namespace

Tags: xamarin

I created a new project and trying to make a phone call via Intent however I am getting
`The type or namespace name 'Intent' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?`.  I'm not entirely sure of what reference or nuget is missing.

Thanks

```
        var number = "0123456789";
        var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionCall);
        intent.SetData(Uri.Parse("tel:" + number));
        StartActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Is this code in the shared Forms project or the Android platform project?

Comment: @Jason it's in the forms.  All I am trying to do is either make a phone call from a button click without the dialer appearing, or start the dialer and then make my forms app the open app and I am just stuck

Comment: @Jason okay intent is in the Android space, but it still pops up the dialer...

Comment: you can do this from shared Forms code using [Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/phone-dialer?tabs=android)

Comment: @Jason it still opens the dial, I want to call from within the app

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10208820?visit_id=638124553292166773-372793257&rd=1#zippy=%2Cpermitted-uses-of-the-sms-and-call-log-permissions

Comment: You can check this article about [Xamarin.forms make phone call without going to dialer in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57369411/xamarin-forms-make-phone-call-without-going-to-dialer-in-android) for more information.